# How to get SQL SERVER 2008 r2 data in a column

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have two different tables : 
Tank & FillingStations

In which one tank can be attached to many fillingstations.
Suppose:

```
SrNo TankID  TankName   TANK_Balance    FillingStation_ID       FS_NAme  BALANCE
1     1      Tank1       5000                A11                FSA11     1545
2     1      Tank1       5000                A12                FSA12     1000
3     1      Tank1       5000                A13                FSA13     800
```

And i want to get a report as like :

```
SrNo TankID  TankName  TANK_Balance   A11    BAL1  A12    BAL2  A13   BAL3 TOTAL
1     1      Tank1     5000           FSA11  1545  FSA12  1000 FSA13  800   3345
```

Comment: This question should be improved: Add your actual table's structures and what you've tried so far. Best was a [Minimal-Complete-Verifyable-Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use *copy'n'pasteable* code, use `DECLARE @Tank Table(...)` or `CREATE TABLE #Tank(...)` to define the structure, fill it with sample data (`INSERT INTO`). You might create a [SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com). In this case you'll get answers in minutes...

Comment: Can you please add more light on the question... details of business rules etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    SrNo INT
    ,TankID INT
    ,TankName VARCHAR(10)
    ,TANK_Balance INT
    ,FillingStation_ID VARCHAR(10)
    ,FS_NAme VARCHAR(10)
    ,BALANCE INT
    )
insert into @Table values 
 (1,1,'Tank1',5000,'A11','FSA11',1545)
,(2,1,'Tank1',5000,'A12','FSA12',1000)
,(3,1,'Tank1',5000,'A13','FSA13',800)


SELECT min(SrNo) as SrNo, TankID
    ,TankName
    ,TANK_Balance
    ,max([A11]) AS [A11]
    ,max([BAL1]) AS [BAL1]
    ,max([A12]) AS [A12]
    ,max([BAL2]) AS [BAL2]
    ,max([A13]) AS [A13]
    ,max([BAL3]) AS [BAL3]
    ,max([BAL1])+max([BAL2])+max([BAL3]) as Total
FROM (
    SELECT SrNo,TankID
        ,TankName
        ,TANK_Balance
        ,FillingStation_ID
        ,replace(FillingStation_ID, 'A1', 'BAL') AS bFillingStation_ID
        ,FS_NAme
        ,BALANCE
    FROM @Table
    ) s
pivot(Max(FS_NAme) FOR FillingStation_Id IN (
            [A11]
            ,[A12]
            ,[A13]
            )) t
pivot(Max(BALANCE) FOR bFillingStation_Id IN (
            [BAL1]
            ,[BAL2]
            ,[BAL3]
            )) t1
GROUP BY TankID
    ,TankName
    ,TANK_Balance
```